# Укажите верное объяснение постановки запятой или её отсутствия на месте скобок в предложении

Tags: русская-графика

Улизнув от двери, пес принял независимый вид () и деловито оглянулся

Answer (score 1):

Сначала найдите основу. Если предложение простое и все действия совершал ПЕС, то зпт. не ставим, т.к. союз И одиночный.